# How can I highlight the specific item in a Kendo UI ListView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-listview

I have a kendo UI ListView implemented in a tabular display as below:

```
Name           user1   user2    user3  
country        usa     uk       germany  
production     5000    6000     1000  
Sales          200     400      100
```

I would like to highlight the 6000 cell which is the production data for user2. I am able to highlight the whole column by using below code but I would like to highlight only a single item (cell). I am using Kendo UI for asp.net MVC. How can I do that using JavaScript/jquery?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
TestHub.client.highlightValue = function (id) {
        var listView = $("#ListView_Test").data("kendoListView");
        listView.element.children("[data-uid='" + listView.dataSource.view()[2].uid + "']").effect("highlight", { color: Red}, 500);
})
};
</script>


    <div class="k-widget">
                <dl>
                    <dd>Name</dd>
                    <dd>Country</dd>
                    <dd>Production</dd>
                    <dd>Sales</dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<Test.Models.TestViewModel>()
    .Name("Test_LV")
    .TagName("div")
    .ClientTemplateId("templateTestLV")
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .SignalR()
                        .Transport(tr => tr
                            .Promise("hubStart")
                                .Hub("TestHub")
                                .Client(c => c.Read("TestLV_Read").Update("TestLV_Update"))
                                .Server(s => s.Read("TestLV_Read").Update("TestLV_Update"))
                            )
                      .Schema(schema => schema
                        .Model(m =>
                        {
                            m.Id(p => p.Id);

                            m.Field(p => p.Name).Editable(false);
                            m.Field(p => p.Country).Editable(false);
                            m.Field(p => p.Production).Editable(false);
                            m.Field(p => p.Sales).Editable(false);
                        })
                     )
                    )
                            .Editable(editable => editable.TemplateName("TestLVEditor"))
            )
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="templateTestLV">
    <div>
        <dl>
            <dd>#=Name</dd>
            <dd>#=Country</dd>
            <dd>#=Production</dd>
            <dd>#=Sales</dd>
        </dl>
        <div class="edit-buttons">
            <a class="k-button k-edit-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: The name of the widget is Kendo ListView, not ListBox. Can you post the entire ListView?

Comment: Edited the question with Full ListView code now. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for being so direct, but your code looks so ugly. I tried to edit it, but it was too much work.

Answer (score 1):

Highlighting the cell is as simple as assigning a class to it (in the client template):

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="templateTestLV">
    <div>
        <dl>
            <dd>#=Name</dd>
            <dd>#=Country</dd>
            <dd class="highlighted">#=Production</dd>
            <dd>#=Sales</dd>
        </dl>
        <div class="edit-buttons">
            <a class="k-button k-edit-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Then, you can apply whatever styling you want to the class `.highlighted` in your css file. But, I assume you want to highlight that cell based on a criteria. In that case, you can add a new Boolean flag to your view model, set the flag to true in your controller, if the production needs to be highlighted based on the criteria, and add the `.highlighted` class only if the flag is set to true. Like below:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="templateTestLV">
    <div>
        <dl>
            <dd>#=Name</dd>
            <dd>#=Country</dd>
            <dd class="#=(IsHighlighted == true ? \"highlighted\" : \"\")#">#=Production</dd>
            <dd>#=Sales</dd>
        </dl>
        <div class="edit-buttons">
            <a class="k-button k-edit-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Yes it is true but I need to highlight a cell programatically(runtime). I am using SignalR here, so event fired ("highlightValue" javascript function here) when someone update the value. How can I get the item(cell) uid here?

Comment: There are kendo state classes, they could be useful to keep the kendo theme,e.g.: `k-state-selected`. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/appearance-styling#the-k-state-classes

Comment: @giparekh, you mean you don't have access to the SignalR code?

Comment: @ataravati, I have a full access to SignalR code. Its not an issue here. What I just want is to get the specific Cell id and highlight it from JavaScript/JQuery function mentioned here. Is it possible? I have achieved the same for Kendo Grid but here I required to use a ListView only.

Comment: @giparekh, you can add the id to the `<dd>` tag just like you add a class. However, I don't understand why you even need it.

Comment: @ataravati, well here is my scenario: When one user edit the production data in a ListView, all the other users get notified by highlighting the updated cell in a ListView. So on update even, I am calling this javascript function to highlight the cell.

Comment: @giparekh, you don't need a javascript code. Do you use a javascript code to update the value of the cell? No, you don't. Imagine that new flag (IsHighlighted) were another column in your ListView. Would you need to update it with javascript? No, you would not.

Comment: @ataravati, Well ListView value will be updated to other users screen in realtime by inbuilt support for SignalR for Kendo widget but I need to just highlight the cell (like a quick flash of color chagne) just to notify users that the value of the cell changed.

Comment: @giparekh, the new flag (property you add to your model) will be no different from the other properties. That property will be uploaded too. So, that's why I told you that in your controller you'll need to set that property based on the criteria you have for highlighting the value. Whenever you are updating the production value in your controller you update the `IsHighlighted` flag too. I think that's clear enough.

Comment: @ataravati, I am sorry but I think you don't understand my question. If you try to implement my code, you will come to know. By saying highlighting here means, just to flash (like stock ticker). I have achieved this nicely with kendo grid for which I can easily get the nth child of any Row. Using a flag is not a solution.

Comment: @giparekh, I do understand what you mean. It looks like you don't understand what I mean. I was trying to help you understand you can do that by just adding a css class conditionally. Good luck!